How to make an input take focus in Qwik?
I'm using Qwik. I have a button. When I click it, an input is shown. How can I make the input take focus too?
const showInput = useSignal(false)

const handleClick = () => {
   showInput.value = !showInput.value
   // I'm stuck here. How can I make the input take focus?
}

return <>
    <button onClick$={handleClick}>Show input</button
    <input class={showInput.value ? " " : "hidden"} />
</>


const showInput = useSignal(false)
const ref = useSignal<HTMLInputElement>();

const handleClick = $(() => {
  showInput.value = !showInput.value;
  const id = setTimeout(() => ref.value?.focus(), 0);
  return () => clearTimeout(id);
})


return <>
    <button onClick$={handleClick}>Show input</button>
    <input ref={ref} class={{"hidden": !showInput.value}} />
</>

This is because the focus should occur after the element becomes visible. One of the options is setTimeout

why do we have to use setTimeout here? Is it a problem related to Qwik?

Alos, I'm not using TypeScript. Can I simply use useSignal()?

This is not the problem of Qwik. It's a rendering problem - if you can call it that. Sure, you will can use JS, just remove types.
